# Using HTML & CSS to create 6 icons (2 and 2 in rows) with text that fall in two lines next to it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 6 icons that have text on the side that falls in two lines. Each icon should be 2 in a line before going on to the next row. See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hmOA.jpg

My initial code attempt below which was followed up with a display: inline-block CSS on the text.

My issues are:

1. Getting the text on the right side to appear in two lines while remaining inline with the icon on the left
2. Creating multiple icons where two fall in a row at a time

```html
<div class="section">

<img src="/uploads/2023/02/Aargang.svg" class="ikon1" alt="Test">

<div class="ikontext">

Year<br>
<strong>2011</strong>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `flex`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
  flex-wrap: wrap; // this makes sure items are dropped to the next row when they are out of space 
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%; // this makes sure there are two items per row
}

.icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.text-bottom {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-top">text top</div>
      <div class="text-bottom">text bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I best add the icon link to the div class icon? Do I add the <img src="/uploads/2023/02/Aargang.svg" alt="Test"> in between each?

Comment: Yes ,that would be one way to do it.